# iOS storyboard passing data navigationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard, navigationcontroller

I have problem with proper passing data between view's but not in standard way.

***Picture describing my problem:***

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jHYC.png]

I **performSegueWithIdentifier** with one of two segue identifiers and then in I want to pass data to ViewController called "Firmy" or "Oddzialy".

Passing data code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sLogowanieFirmy"]) {
      FirmyVC *firmyVC = [segue destinationViewController];
      firmyVC.tabFirmy = self.tabFirmy;
  }
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sLogowanieOddzialy"]) {
      OddzialyVC *oddzialyVC = [segue destinationViewController];
      oddzialyVC.wybranaFirma = [self.tabFirmy objectAtIndex:0];
  }
}
```

Problem is with method **[segue destinationViewController]** becouse destinationViewController for segue is NavigationViewController.

So what is proper way to pass data and have independent Navigation Controllers?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the `NSNotificationCenter` class. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: There is no more convenient way?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has a property called `topViewController` which returns the view controller that is at the top of the stack.

So your `prepareForSegue:` method may look something like this...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sLogowanieFirmy"]) {
        UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
        FirmyVC *firmyVC = (FirmyVC *)nav.topViewController;
        firmyVC.tabFirmy = self.tabFirmy;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in swift:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{    
    if (segue.identifier == "sLogowanieFirmy") {
        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController 
        let firmyVC = nav.topViewController as! FirmyVC
        firmyVC.tabFirmy = self.tabFirmy            
    }

    // etc...
}
```