# Passing Data to Tabbar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard project and I would like to pass some data from a view into a tab bar controller, the information will be spread out between the tabs. After doing some research I found a very similar issue: [iOS storyboard passing data navigationViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429088/ios-storyboard-passing-data-navigationviewcontroller) but the only issue with this solution is that it was not transferring to a tab bar controller. I was wondering would I have to pass the data to each tab or can I pass it to the tab bar controller and then spread it from there? Thank you for your help in advance!

I am currently using the following; but, I get an error:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FoodPage"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
    FoodViewController *destViewController = (FoodViewController*) nav.topViewController;
    destViewController.Foods = [foodArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get a reference to your `UINavigationController` in your case, you have to do the following and specify the correct index to your `tabBarController` *first*:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:<THE_INDEX_NUMBER_FOR_YOUR_NAVIGATION_CONTROLLER];
```

Once you have done so, then you retrieve a reference to your `FoodViewController` by specifying again the index number for it on your `UINavigationController` (i.e. if it's on top, then `0`):

```
FoodViewController *destViewController = (FoodViewController*) [self.nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

***Update***:

Now that I got a better idea what you would like to achieve:

You are using `UITabbarController` in which your others controllers are embedded.

***Scenario / Example Case***:

Let say we had 2 view controllers, controller A and controller B, respectively, both are embedded in a `UITabbarController`.

***What we want:***

We are trying to change the text of a `UILabel` in controller B from controller A.

*First*, declare a `property` in controller B in .h:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) UILabel *aLabelInControllerB;
```

*Second*, declare a a property (or ivar) in your controller A:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) ControllerB *controllerB;
```

Since you are using `UITabbarController` you don't need to use segue, you could simply
get a hold of `UITabbarController` via `self.tabBarController`;

***Question***: "how would I know then when my tab bar controller is tapped and then change the text of the label in controller B?"

*We do this:*

Set controller A as the delegate of `UITabbarController` by:

In controller A .h, add:

```
@interface <Your_Controller> : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

In `viewDidLoad` of controller A:

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

And in controller A .m, implement this method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.controllerB = (ControllerB *) [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    //In our example here, we only have 2 view controllers (A and B)
    //So, index 1 is where controller B resides.

    self.controllerB.aLabelInControllerB.text = @"Hello!";
    //This will change the text of the label in controller B
}
```

And as controller B appears, you will see that the text of the label will be changed to "Hello!"

Setting a `NSString` in controller B follows the same procedure.

Ex: `self.controllerB.stringInControllerB = @"Hi from controller B!";`

Hope that helps.

---

---

***Update 2:***

Segue'ing from table view cell to a tab bar controller? Oki.. Here is the solution. I am only using one cell in my example, so should it become desired that you would like to have more cells in the future, I would leave that up to you to adjust.

Let's take a look at the storyboard layout:

[image]

In storyboard, <kbd>control</kbd> drag from your cell to the tab bar controller.

Add a `UINavigationController` like in the picture.

In your `UITableViewController` .m:

Add 2 properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *myTabbarController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourFirstViewController *myFirstViewController;
```

***Just a friendly reminder:***

Remember to add:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Add the following in your table view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    self.myTabbarController = (UITabBarController*) [segue destinationViewController];
    self.myFirstViewController = [self.myTabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.myFirstViewController.stringFromTableViewController = @"Hi from TableViewController!";
}
```

And in `myFirstViewController`, add 2 properties in .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringFromTableViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourSecondViewController *secondViewController;
```

Like from the second edit above, have your first view controller to be still the delegate of UITabBarControllerDelegate and implement this method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.secondViewController = (YourSecondViewController*) viewController;
    self.secondViewController.aLabel.text = self.stringFromTableViewController; 
}
```

Just like before, nothing needs to be changed in `SecondViewController`.

I ran this myself; should be good to go for your setup.

Enjoy.

Comment: When you refer to the index are you referring to which tab index to send the information to or the index of the tab bar controller? Also, where would I get the index of the tab bar controller? Thanks again!

Comment: @paul590 Yes, if you have, let say, a `UINavigationController` on the second tab, then the corresponding index number would be 1 on your `tabBarController`. So, you first need to get a hold of that by specifying 1 as index; once you get a hold of the `UINavigationController`, you would need again to specify an index for your `FoodViewController`, which normally, as I presume, would be `0`, on the top.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify that I have a tableview of food in which when the user selects a food it will send this information to a tab bar controller where there is the food name tab, description tab, and how to make it tab. Would I still use the same information you provided me with?

Comment: @paul590 That's correct. When you have a `tabBarController` in which your other controllers are embedded, you first need to get a reference to the controller you wish to get a hold of by specifying the index number on the `tabBarController`, once you get a hold of the controller from the `tabBarController`, then you send the information to that controller. So, in your case, you need to get a hold of the controller from the `tabBarController` by specifying the tab (index); once that is done, then you send the data to it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, it makes a lot of sense! I am currently trying your code but I am getting an error on this line FoodViewController *destViewController = (FoodViewController*) [self.nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; it says property nav not found in foodlistviewcontroller. Do i have to create the nav outside the segue?

Comment: @paul590 No, if you don't have a `UINavigationController` you don't need that. But since that's what you wrote in your question, I thought you had a `UINavigationController`. If you don't, simply specifying the index for `FoodViewController` in your `tabBarController` should do the job.

Comment: i see! would I end passing the information the regular way as well? for example: food.string = @"hello";

Comment: Def will do I am just trying to understand the way to send the information still, it is not sending to the view for some reason. I have the following code:

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FoodPage"]) {
    FoodViewController *destViewController = (FoodViewController*) nav.topViewController;
    destViewController.FoodString = @"hello";
}

Comment: I meant food.FoodString = @"hello"; }** Would I also include the passing of information to the other tabs in this segue?

Comment: Thank you for the help this is definitely useful, but unfortunately it is not what I am looking for unless I am understanding incorrectly. I have added a picture to my question to clarify what I would like to do. The methos that you provided me with will help me once I'm inside the tab controller but if I want to import a string from outside the tab controller I would still need a segue?

Comment: Can you let me know the solution in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to access data from the TabBar within the TabBar's child viewcontrollers themselves, like so:

```
MyTabbarViewController *tabbar = (MyTabbarViewController *)self.tabBarController;
NSLog(@"%@", tabbar.data);
```

This way you only have to set the data in the TabBar like shown above, and then access it whenever you need it in a child view.

Comment: Used this solution, easiest one. Not completely sold on having the child view controllers of the tabbar controller to know of it's parent though.