# Swift set variable to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have two tabs. And i want to set data from one tab to another. For example i have a code that switch to another tab:

```
func foundCode(code: String) {
    print("Code has been found: \(code)")
    // MySecondViewController.codeSetter(code);
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

What is the best way to set it? Or maybe delegate this variable... But how ?

Comment: You can use defaults if you data is small.

Comment: In first tab i calculated code and after all operations i want to switch tab and show information based on this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a variable in your first controller like:

```
var code:String!
```

and in your function:

```
func foundCode(code: String) {
    print("Code has been found: \(code)")
    self.code = code

    // MySecondViewController.codeSetter(code);
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

I think you should be able to access it in your second controller (i think the variables you declare in top are accessible in all of your classes)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for you using `NSUserDefaults`:

Store your data into first tab:

```
let testInstance = 1
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(testInstance, forKey: "pass")
```

Now in another tab you can read that data from memory this way:

```
let instanceFromAnotherTab = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("pass")
print(instanceFromAnotherTab)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: can i do this with "segue" ??

Comment: This is very bad practice, storing and reading from UserDefaults, every time you change between tabs. Better way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21271948/3207979

Comment: Can you explain why this is a bad practice because I have never seen any down side of  `NSUserDefaults`. @DejanSkledar

Comment: I'll just say, that things already get unnecessarily complicated, when you try to save a Custom object to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: This is even worse than using the appDelegate to pass data between controllers.

Comment: here are apple allow to setIntegerForKey then why that is not good @abizen and dejan Skleder please review this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger:forKey: And if realy not got then apple have to remove NSUserDefault from development side