# Can't pass data from UITableviewController into ViewController - keep getting Swift dynamic Cast Class Unconditional error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I'm simply trying to pass core data that displays in a TableViewController to another ViewController - there seems to be something wrong with my prepareForSegueCode.  Trying to pass the data and load it in viewDidLoad of the ViewController.  Any help is so much appreciated - been working on this for hours with no luck.

TableViewController Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyEventsTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var myEvents:[myEventsData] = []

var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController!

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!,atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!){

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    myEvents = controller.fetchedObjects as [myEventsData]

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "myEventsCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyEventsTableViewCell

    let eventData = myEvents [indexPath.row]
    cell.eventNameLabel.text = "Name: " + eventData.eventName
    cell.startDateLabel.text = "Start: " + eventData.startDate
    cell.endDateLabel.text = "End: " + eventData.endDate

    cell.eventData = eventData

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()



    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue (segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEventDetails" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as MyEventDetailsViewController

        destinationController.eventData! = myEvents[indexPath.row]
        }
           }
}
```

DestinationViewController Code:

```
import UIKit

class MyEventDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {


var eventData:myEventsData!


@IBOutlet weak var eventName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var startDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var endDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var details: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postComment: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var checkIn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var addPhoto: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myWineJournal: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.eventName.text = eventData.eventName
    self.startDate.text = eventData.startDate
    self.endDate.text = eventData.endDate
    self.details.text = eventData.details

}
```

Comment: Is there a question?  What results are you expecting?  What results are you not seeing?  Are you seeing a crash?

Comment: @David: that is mentioned in the title. Mike, however I suggest to explicitly and clearly report the error in the question itself

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSegueDemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an error in this line:

```
destinationController.eventData! = myEvents[indexPath.row]
```

as you are using the forced unwrapping operator for assignment - that's not necessary as it should simply be:

```
destinationController.eventData = myEvents[indexPath.row]
```

Since the `eventData` property doesn't seem to be initialized, I'd expect a different exception though:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

---

**Addendum**

The cast exception could be caused by this:

```
let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as MyEventDetailsViewController
```

Are you sure you have set the custom class in IB for that view controller?

**Update**

As outlined in comments, it turns out the problem is that there's a navigation controller between the source and the destination view controller. The problem has been fixed as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8429482/148357), consisting of retrieving the top view controller from the nav controller.

Comment: Thanks Antonio - took out the exclamation point (a result of my many attempts to fix) and double checked and am sure the custom class is set in the view controller.

Comment: libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x10b7f0860:  pushq  %rbp
0x10b7f0861:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10b7f0864:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x10b7f0867:  je     0x10b7f089e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10b7f0869:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x10b7f0873:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x10b7f0876:  jne    0x10b7f089e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62

Comment: FingerLakesUncorked`@objc FingerLakesUncorked.MyEventsTableViewController.prepareForSegue (FingerLakesUncorked.MyEventsTableViewController)(ObjectiveC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.AnyObject>) -> () at MyEventsTableViewController.swift:

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and inspect the actual type of the destination view controller

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "inspect the actual type"  by doing this I also can see that there are no values in eventData as you already thought - ugh this is frustrating as I am not getting what I am doing wrong

Comment: After the breakpoint is hit, from the variables view expand the `segue` variable, then `UIStoryboardSegue`, and check what's the type of the `_destinationViewController` property

Comment: _destinationViewController UINavigationController * 0x7fe9d15a1bf0 0x00007fe9d15a1bf0
[0] UINavigationController

Comment: That's the reason why if fails: the destination view controller is a `UINavigationViewController`, not `MyEventDetailsViewController`. Probably  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429088/ios-storyboard-passing-data-navigationviewcontroller) can help you fixing it.

Comment: worked brilliantly - thanks Antonio....of course now I have to work on this:  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Cool - one step at a time :) I've updated my answer to include the solution.