# how to pass the value on one view to another view in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, navigation, storyboard

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

    abcViewController *vc = [[abcViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"abcViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.str = @"hello";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429088/ios-storyboard-passing-data-navigationviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code

UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierName"];
vc.label = @"Text";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If yes please make it accepted and click on up vote button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to send string value from one view to another using storyboard.
In first view controller declare the variable in .h file like NSString str; and in second view controller declare the variable in .h like NSString newStr;.
Then in first view controller of .m file create second view object using storyboard -
SecondViewController *svc = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
And send variable using this object to second view-
        svc.newStr = str;